# Conditional JoinColumn in Entity JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I do have a situation where I need to fetch data from three different tables based on some condition.
Eg.

```
@Entity
class Order{
   id;
   type;
   typeId;

   @Join with boqTable to get the Boq Associated with if type == BOQ and id = typeId
   @Join with customTable to get custom data associated if type == CUSTOM and id = typeId
}
```

I should able to insert and update the child tables using the Order entity.
How do I can this using JPA/Hibernate.. I searched a lot and i couldn't get any solution, apart from manually doing it at the service level instead of handling at the Entity Model

Comment: There are no conditional joins.

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of 2 non-JPA compliant, Hibernate specific features. If the condition is static then see the Hibernate `@Where` annotation. See section 2.4.6:

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/

Otherwise see Hibernate filters:

> Hibernate3 has the ability to pre-define filter criteria and attach
>   those filters at both a class level and a collection level. A filter
>   criteria allows you to define a restriction clause similar to the
>   existing "where" attribute available on the class and various
>   collection elements. These filter conditions, however, can be
>   parameterized. The application can then decide at runtime whether
>   certain filters should be enabled and what their parameter values
>   should be. Filters can be used like database views, but they are
>   parameterized inside the application.

https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/filters.html